# How to send email from my own server using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, flask, flask-mail

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

mail_settings = {
    "MAIL_SERVER": 'mail.hi.in',
    "MAIL_PORT": 465,
    "MAIL_USE_TLS": False,
    "MAIL_USE_SSL": True,
    "MAIL_USERNAME": abcde,
    "MAIL_PASSWORD": password
}

app.config.update(mail_settings)
mail = Mail(app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        msg = Message(subject="Hello",
                      sender=app.config.get("support@hi.in"),
                      recipients=["dfjhnk@gmail.com"],
                      body="This is a test email I sent with Gmail and Python!")
        mail.send(msg)
```

Error Saying:
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Is a SMTP server installed in `'mail.hi.in'`, listening on port 465?

Answer (score -1):

> This is a test email I sent with Gmail and Python!
>   I see that you use Gmail, so if you don't have enabled "Less secure apps on your google account" go [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)